# Tengo un error en el servidor de aplicación al ejecutar el proyecto Web del tipo Asp .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, mvc, iis, windows10

buenos días, tardes o noches:

Estoy teniendo este error al momento de ejecutar mi proyecto web.
El proyecto esta creado en Asp.Net con plataforma .NET Framework 4.5.
Quisiera saber como resolver esa excepción.
La aplicación tiene solamente la información que se crea al momento de crear un proyecto de este tipo. Estoy utilizando el Visual Studio 2022 y el sistema operativo es un Windows 10 Home.
Tengo instalado el Internet Information Service(IIS), me gustaría que funcionara de forma local por el momento, porque es para hacer prácticas.

Saludos y desde ya muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos Dafneax, ¿Podrías agregar más detalles por favor? Aquí unas recomendaciones para preguntar https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Gracias :D

Comment: Qué serían más detalles?, versión del sistema operativo o del framework que esta usando el proyecto?, es sólo un proyecto de prueba sin información (sólo el código básico que genera el Visual Studio al momento de crear el proyecto), solo es un proyecto creado básico, con patrón de diseño MVC y cuando intento ejecutarlo aparece el mensaje de error de excepción.

Comment: Voy a volver a crear un proyecto y a registrar los datos de la creación para que se entienda mejor con cual de los tipos de proyectos estoy teniendo la excepción del servidor.

Comment: También agrega cómo haces la puesta en producción en tu IIS Local.